# Can't get my CSS to work

Tags: html, css

I can't get my CSS to work.

[codepen.io](http://codepen.io/audedesigns/pen/ZBZweW)

Even though the code is working, it won't give me a black background?

Code:

```css
potnav {
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="potnav">hei</div>
```

Comment: You need to add a period at the start of your class name in your CSS. `.potnav`

Comment: Your given codepen url is not working. if you don't want to use **dot(.)** then you can use like **[class=potnav]{ padding: 16px;
color: white; background-color: black; }**.

Comment: `.potnav` for class or `#potnav` for id

Answer (score 2):

Error with the class declaration syntax. Use `.ClassName` to apply style. See the working sample.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .potnav {
            padding: 16px;
            color: white;
            background-color: black!important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="potnav">hei</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the period (.) at the class name.

```
.potnav{
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the point to indicate that "potnav" is a class

```css
.potnav{
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="potnav">hei</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use **dot(.)** while referring to a class in CSS and **pound(#)** while referring to an id.

Below is an example usage of potnav as class and id in CSS.

```
.potnav {
  /*css properties related to this class goes here */
}

#potnav {
  /*css properties related to this id goes here */
}
```